# print all the lines having a variable value greater than certain number

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

need help with unix command:

I want to list/grep all the lines having "abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb" with etime greater than 5 from a log file:

Snippet from log:

```
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] BIND RES conn=74242995 op=1 msgID=2 result=0 authDN="ldapguid=abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb,dc=abc,dc=com" etime=6
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] BIND RES conn=74242987 op=1 msgID=2 result=0 authDN="ldapguid=abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb,dc=abc,dc=com" etime=7
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] EXTENDED RES conn=74243079 op=0 msgID=1 name="StartTLS" oid="1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20037" result=0 etime=0
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] SEARCH RES conn=74242947 op=2 msgID=3 result=0 nentries=0 etime=1
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] SEARCH RES conn=74242945 op=2 msgID=3 result=0 nentries=0 etime=0
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] EXTENDED RES conn=74243083 op=0 msgID=1 name="StartTLS" oid="1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20037" result=0 etime=1
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] BIND RES conn=74242989 op=1 msgID=2 result=0 authDN="ldapguid=abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb,dc=abc,dc=com" etime=2
```

Desired output:

```
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] BIND RES conn=74242995 op=1 msgID=2 result=0 authDN="ldapguid=abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb,dc=abc,dc=com" etime=6
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] BIND RES conn=74242987 op=1 msgID=2 result=0 authDN="ldapguid=abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb,dc=abc,dc=com" etime=7
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please explain how you are supposed to write a MCVE when asking for help with the use of a single command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb logfile |awk -F "etime=" '$2>5{print}' > modifiedlog.txt
```

sample output:

```
auxilus@ubuntu:~$ cat logfile 
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] BIND RES conn=74242995 op=1 
msgID=2 result=0 authDN="ldapguid=abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb,dc=abc,dc=com" etime=6
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] BIND RES conn=74242987 op=1 msgID=2 result=0 authDN="ldapguid=abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb,dc=abc,dc=com" etime=7
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] EXTENDED RES conn=74243079 op=0 msgID=1 name="StartTLS" oid="1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20037" result=0 etime=0
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] SEARCH RES conn=74242947 op=2 msgID=3 result=0 nentries=0 etime=1
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] SEARCH RES conn=74242945 op=2 msgID=3 result=0 nentries=0 etime=0
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] EXTENDED RES conn=74243083 op=0 msgID=1 name="StartTLS" oid="1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20037" result=0 etime=1
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] BIND RES conn=74242989 op=1 msgID=2 result=0 authDN="ldapguid=abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb,dc=abc,dc=com" etime=2

auxilus@ubuntu:~$ grep abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb logfile |awk -F "etime=" '$2>5{print}'
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] BIND RES conn=74242995 op=1 msgID=2 result=0 authDN="ldapguid=abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb,dc=abc,dc=com" etime=6
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] BIND RES conn=74242987 op=1 msgID=2 result=0 authDN="ldapguid=abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb,dc=abc,dc=com" etime=7
auxilus@ubuntu:~$
```

better version:

```
awk -F "etime=" '/abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb/ {if ($2>5) {print}}' logfile
```

Comment: Awk can search for a regex just fine; the [`grep` is useless.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: I've modified my answer, thanks for the review!

Comment: This can still be simplified further; `{ print }` is the default action, so the entire script can be `'/regex/ && $2 > 5'`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want lines ending with `etime=` and a umber between 0 and 5.
From the other lines you only want to see the lines with `abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb`. Combined:

```
sed -n '/etime=[0-5]$/d;/abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb/p' logfile
```

Comment: Quite a nice and concise solution.

Answer (score -1):

A simple `grep` solution using basic regular expressions that will handle single `etime=` with values `6-9` or any multi-digit `etime=` (e.g. `etime=[6-9]` or `etime=[0-9][0-9][0-9]*`) would be:

```
$ grep 'abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb.*etime=\([6-9]\|[0-9][0-9][0-9]*\).*$' file
```

Using your `file` as input results in the following:

```
$ grep 'abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb.*etime=\([6-9]\|[0-9][0-9][0-9]*\).*$' file
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] BIND RES conn=74242995 op=1 msgID=2 result=0 authDN="ldapguid=abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb,dc=abc,dc=com" etime=6
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] BIND RES conn=74242987 op=1 msgID=2 result=0 authDN="ldapguid=abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb,dc=abc,dc=com" etime=7
```

If your file also contained a two (or more) digit `etime`, that would be caught as well, e.g.

```
access:[29/Dec/2018:14:59:38 +0000] BIND RES conn=74242989 op=1 msgID=2 result=0 authDN="ldapguid=abdc7dac-abdf-4088-ba87-ca5ee765f3eb,dc=abc,dc=com" etime=12
```

You can adjust the numeric range to tailor the match to your needs.

Comment: Thank you @Auxilus and all who responded to the query.  I am all set !